# Grails social plugins for facebook give error response after user authenticate application

Tags: facebook, grails

I am new to grails and i am trying to add facebook plugin to my web application. i have successfully(as i believe) installed plugins and addED necessary code in my application. I followed the documentation found at http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/ , when I run my app I see the facebook connect button on gsp page,after clicking on connect button a popup opens up asking for permissions required in app and when user clicks on allow button i receive error "No authentication provider found". I dont know where i am wrong ,can any one help me please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any errors in the log?

Comment: Please show your configuration for the plugin

Comment: i have following setting - grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [
 'myAuthenticationProvider',
 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
 'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']

grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.domain.classname='com.example.FacebookUser'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.appId='**********'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.secret='************'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.filter.redirect.failureHandler='redirectFailureHandler'

Comment: Please add settings into your original question text

Comment: As I see, you have redefined provider list, with your own. So your `myAuthenticationProvider` should supports `FacebookAuthToken`. Does it?

Comment: Or just keep original `facebookAuthProvider` in this list, before anonymous and rememberMe providers

Comment: when myAuthenticationProvider called its support method allways return false.

Comment: So, if it returns false, what you expect? what the reason to add own implementation if it always return false? Anyway, to fix `No authentication provider found` just return original provider into this list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have custom list of providers:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [ 'myAuthenticationProvider',
    'anonymousAuthenticationProvider', 
    'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']
```

And none of them supports `FacebookAuthToke`, so Spring Security cannot authenticate using Facebook Authentication plugin.

If you really need to have custom provider, just put original provider into this list:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [ 'myAuthenticationProvider',
    'facebookAuthProvider', 
    'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
    'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']
```